# fade in div container when all images within have loaded

Tags: jquery

I have this div container and within I have images, I'd like to fade in the whole `.slider` container when all images within it have loaded. How can I do this with jquery? Thanks!

```
 <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide1 slide">
                <img src="img/model1.png" >
             </div>
<div class="slide2 slide">
                <img src="img/model1.png" >
             </div>
<div class="slide3 slide">
                <img src="img/model1.png" >
             </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $slider = $('.slider'),
        $imgs = $slider.find('img'),
        counter = 0;
    //wait for the images to load
    $imgs.load(function () {
        //increment the loaded image counter
        counter++;
        //if the counter matches the images count then show the slider
        if (counter == $imgs.length) {
            $slider.show()
        }
    }).filter(function () {
        //trigger the load event for already loaded images
        return this.complete
    }).trigger('load');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin will really make everything much easier. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QK868/1/).

```
imagesLoaded($(".slider"), function() {
    $(".slider").fadeIn("slow");
});
```